# Unity5 imported models show no texture

Tags: textures, models, materials, unity

I've got a problem with Unity materials.
I'm a beginner- so I used Wings3d for creating 3d models.

But there's a little Problem.
Both objects on the picture below have the same material(a Standart Material with 0 smoothness, 0 metallic and only a only an Albedo picture)-but obviously the right one has no texture( and that's the problem).
[image: a Cube from unity and a cube-like object from wings3d]

First I ignored it and used a custom shader ("Custom/WorldCoord Diffuse) which I found in a package for fixing it. Poorly this shader doesn't support Normal or Height maps and strangely slows down my game extremly (my scene with only Standart shaders ~80 FPS | my scene with this strange shader~7 FPS).

I don't know how to write my own shaders and I don't know blender, and I don't have much time to fix this.

Comment: It looks like the Wings3D object doesn't have texture coordinates. Did you assign texture coordinates to your model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the Wings3D object doesn't have texture coordinates. There is a texture applied, it's just not applied correctly. Without texture coordinates, it'll just stretch a single pixel of the texture over the entire object.

Comment: Well. .. I've got only surface textures( like wood or stone)...                I don't have much experience with 3d modelling and I've never seen how to do that....do you know maybe a shader which works without texture coordinates?

Comment: Look in the documentation for Wings3D and you should find a way to assign uv coordinates to your mesh that will then be imported into Unity with the model.

Comment: There are ways to display textures without requiring texture coordinates in the model, but those are mostly special effects that won't look anything like the texturing on the Unity cube. That look requires texture coordinates; I haven't used Wings3D in a long time, but I'm 99% sure it can do simple box coordinates.

Comment: yes, I googled it too- but I've got around 100 models in my project and fixing them all till tomorrow isn't possible- now I'm looking for an efficient shader which uses Global Coordinates